# PHP foreach loop is breaking my variable?

Tags: php, variables, scope

Simply put, I have a variable I declare, I run a foreach loop, the variable is accessible everywhere inside the foreach loop (I use var_dump() to show its value at different points inside the loop), but immediately after the foreach loop, the variable is gone? The page breaks, php won't display anything and html stops rendering. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$canyonPages = []; // the variable in question


$page_ids = get_all_page_ids(); // wordpress function

foreach ($page_ids as $id) {
  
  $args = array(
    'page_id' => $id
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args); // Wordpress query to loop through all pages

  if ($query->have_posts()){ while ($query->have_posts()){ 
    $query->the_post();

// logic inside wp_query to grab the pages with the correct content.  
    if (have_rows('area')) {
      continue;
    }

    if (have_rows('canyon_template')) {
      array_push($canyonPages, $id);
    }

  }}
  wp_reset_postdata(); // Wordpress function to reset wordpress loop. allows me to start new wp_query

};  

// html stops rendering.

$canyon_count = count($canyonPages);
var_dump($canyon_count); // doesn't show up at all
?>
```

I will include all the places I have examined the $canyonPages variable using var_dump() and when it stops working. basically, as soon as the foreach loop ends, the variable seems to disappear and I cannot figure out what is going on.

```
<?php
$canyonPages = []; // the variable in question


$page_ids = get_all_page_ids();

foreach ($page_ids as $id) {

  var_dump($canyonPages); // works, shows empty array.

  $args = array(
    'page_id' => $id
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args); 

  if ($query->have_posts()){ while ($query->have_posts()){ 
    $query->the_post();

        var_dump($canyonPages); // works, starts with empty array and gets bigger as the loop progresses.

  
    if (have_rows('area')) {
      continue;
    }

    var_dump($canyonPages); // works, starts with empty array and gets bigger as the loop progresses.

    if (have_rows('canyon_template')) {
      array_push($canyonPages, $id);
    }

    var_dump($canyonPages); // works, starts with empty array and gets bigger as the loop progresses.

  }}
  wp_reset_postdata();

var_dump($canyonPages); // works, starts with empty array and gets bigger as the loop progresses.

};

var_dump($canyonPages); // doesn't work. Won't show an empty array. Doesn't show anything.

// html stops rendering.

$canyon_count = count($canyonPages);
var_dump($canyon_count);
?>
```

I've tried adding `global $canyonPages` to the top of the foreach loop, to the top of the ifwhile statement of the wp_query, but that didn't work. I can't figure out why the variable seems to be disappearing. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `global` is only useful when you are trying to access a variable from inside a function. That's not the case here.

Comment: `html stops rendering`...is there a PHP error? Do you have PHP error reporting (or logging) switched on?

Comment: I'm suspicious of that semi-column `;` after the closing bracket `}` of the foreach loop

Comment: Oh, that was just something I added to see if it would help lol. It still does the same thing without it.

Comment: `just something I added to see if it would help`...hm...just some friendly advice: programming isn't a guessing game, it's an engineering discipline. Add things if you have a reason to do so, not because you hope it might be magic. That way lies confusion and [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Generally you make a lot more progress with a reasoned approach :-)

Comment: "*Won't show an empty array. Doesn't show anything*" If `var_dump()` does not display anything, it means it is not running.  Your variable is not disappearing, the code is not reaching that point.  Something unexpected is happening on one  iteration of one of the loops (you have 2 nested loops).  You need to debug and find which values in your loops are causing the problem, what value is `$id` when it crashes, and which post, and why do they cause a problem?  Maybe you are not displaying errors, in which case there might be something in your PHP/web server logs.

Comment: There's no need to put `if(x)` around `while(x)`. If the condition isn't true, the first iteration of `while(x)` will never be entered, so they're equivalent. You only need that structure if you have an `else` that shows a message like "No results found"